# Find the max profit (max - min) in an array of values using c++

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

I have a project that reads as follows:

Given an array of stock prices during the span of a single day in chronological order. 
Find the biggest profit that could have been made by first buying and then selling the stock.
The function receives a pointer to an array, and a corresponding array size.

Basically I have to find a min value, and then find a max value (with a higher index) to yield the biggest possible profit. Max - Min.

```
Sample data:
price[0]=100; 
price[1]=5; 
price[2]=7; 
price[3]=34; 
price[4]=100;   
price[5]=2;     

Output Based on Sample Data: 
The best possible profit would be if one bought at point 1 and sold at point 4 for 100-5 = 95 a share.
```

I was thinking - I have two small min and max functions. 
The Min function finds the min value returning the index of the min position. 
Then we have the pointer move to the min_index +1 and pass that to the function to find the max value. Then the max function returns the max_index;
Then we would take the max_index value and subtract the min_index value. I don't know if this is the best approach or even a good approach. I'm also not entirely sure of the best way to code this in c++

 Thank you.

Comment: Doesn't works for `2 100 1 2`.

Comment: They aren't sorted - they need to remain in the order they are because you can only sell after you buy. So the max value has to be found after the min value. The goal is to find the biggest difference so the max value has to be after the min value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Time zero: Buy and sell at the same time, no profit
int best_buy_index = 0;
int best_sell_index = 0;
int min_index = 0;
int best_profit = 0;

for (int i = 1; i < prices.size(); ++i) {
  // Profit we'd get if we had bought at the lowest price yet and sold now.
  int profit = (prices[i] - prices[min_index]);

  if (profit > best_profit) {
    // We found a better solution.
    best_buy_index = min_index;
    best_sell_index = i;
    best_profit = profit;
  } else if (prices[i] < prices[min_index]) {
    // Potentially better buy time.
    min_index = i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try:

```
int bestProfit(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    if (v.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    int min = v[0];
    int profit = 0;
    for (auto e : v) {
        profit = std::max(profit, e - min);
        min = std::min(min, e);
    }
    return profit;
}
```

Comment: how would this change if min value isn't v[0] or array[0] but rather a min value in the duration of the day.

Comment: @YelizavetaYR: It progressively finds the min value. It starts with the assumption that `v[0]` is the min, but then updates the min any time it finds a "better" (or lower) min value. If `v[0]` is not the true minimum, it will eventually find that out and update min to the true minimum.

Comment: in the for loop - what is e?

Comment: @Cornstalks you need a min value that happens before a max value. i.e. `2 100 1 98` has a max profit of 98. I think you correctly find the max profit, but you'd identify the wrong time to buy.

Comment: I use a for range, you may use instead `for (std::size_t i = 0; i != v.size(); ++i) { const int e = v[i]; ...`